# Moved site and now I'm getting Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEnvironment..ctor()'

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have an MVC 6 project using visualstudio.com for TFS.  I tried making a copy of my project on my local machine so that I could switch to a local TFS server.  After doing this, both of the projects now throw the following error.

Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEnvironment..ctor()'.

They both compile successfully, but will not run.

[image]

Comment: Did you update the KRE and ran `kpm restore`?

Comment: I did not update anything.  I just made a copy of the solution.  Do I need toupdate the KRE?  Could it have updated itself?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured out the answer.  In my project.json file I had a reference to get the latest version of SignalR and all my other references had the entire version.  It looks like Signalr got an update and uses newer dlls.  So when I got the latest SignalR dlls it broke my project.  It seems it was just a coincidence that my projects stopped working when I made the copy. (Or it grabbed the latest version of the SignalR dll, dont know)

Example:

I had the following:
"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-*" and in beta1 it uses 1.0.0-beta1 dlls from Microsoft.Framework.

In my cache I saw SignalR was upgraded to beta2.

All my other references use "1.0.0-beta1"

Hope this makes sense.